# How to fill all workspaces with one really wide image on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, desktop-customization, workspace

Is there a way in Ubuntu to set a really long picture as wallpaper so each workspace would have different part of the image? I.e. the image would start on workspace 1 and continue to workspace 2, 3, 4?

I know I can split the image to parts and use wallpapoz to set different parts to different workspaces, but wallpapoz is discontinued and frankly I'd prefer use something that works out of the box, without image editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu uses the GNOME desktop by default, and GNOME does not offer desktop-specific wallpapers. There are various hacks involving Compiz or other things, but I haven't been able to make any of them work well.

So no, you can't do that. Maybe you can in KDE.

Comment: Looks like you are right